# How to get value from resultset column name in java?

Tags: java, excel, jdbc-odbc

I'm reading value from Excel using jdbc-odbc in java ? One of the column name start with . how to read the from that column ? Im getting error unknown column while reading..

```
//String filesend = resultset.getString(".file send");
```

Please help me..

Comment: I think you are using the alias column name..
Paste your query, which is execute?

Comment: No, its Excel sheet column name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try escaping the . ?
A good idea would be to see the name of the column using ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName(index) method.

Comment: yeah. once you debug to see what's the column name that resultset hold you will be able to use it in above getString() method.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to get connection

Here is the code:

```
FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(myInput);

XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0); 
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(1);
cell.setCellValue(123);
```